# The element type 'List<Answer>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. Error with mapping

Tags: flutter, dart

It's neither accepting the three dots (...) nor the map function.

What should be the exact fix?

```
body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']),
            ...(questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>).map((answer){
              return Answer(_answerQuestion,answer);
            }).toList(),
```

Comment: is `Answer` a widget?

Comment: yes,its a class that extends stateless widget.